# Referencing files outside of build context

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I would like to organize my docker image files based on the service i'm building in a `.docker` directory. To start, I'd like to build out the web docker container. Note how in the docker file, I am copying the webroot files to the docker container. The issue is, in my `docker-compose.yml`, when the image gets built, it references the root from the `.docker/web` directory instead of the actual webroot. I tried using a relative path in the docker file which didn't seem to work. Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
      build:
        context: .docker/web
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM webdevops/php-apache-dev

ADD ./../../ /var/www/html
```

Error

```
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: ADD failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../../
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be helpful to see more of the directory tree you're working with, but I'll make a guess at what you're trying to do.

The `context` setting in `docker-compose.yml` defines the starting point for relative paths passed as the first argument to `ADD`, and relative paths can't point to directories higher than that in the tree. If I understand your case correctly, you should be able to do:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: .docker/web/Dockerfile
```

And change your `Dockerfile` to have:

```
ADD . /var/www/html
```